# KVM in Ubuntu cannot trap Windows7 keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, linux-kvm

I am running Windows7 as a guest OS inside KVM running in Ubuntu Desktop 10.04

Everytime I do Alt+Tab within Windows7, the shortcut is caught by Ubuntu.

How can I 'trap' the shortcut to stay within the guest OS?

I tried running the guest OS fullscreen but Alt+Tab still escapes.

Running guest OS fullscreen with display scaled up seems to trap Alt+Tab within KVM, but somehow guest OS is running very very slowly in that mode.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use Vitual Machine Manager to run a VNC shell. Ctrl+Alt will lock you in the window and any further commands will go directly to that shell.